# Matlab - Differences between rng and rand

Tags: matlab

I was trying to run some Monte-Carlo simulations and if I used:

rng(seed, 'Twister');

For some reason I would get "Option Values Can not be Negative" errors in the blsimpv function, but if I just use the rand (seed) function, the problem seems to be OK (having everything else the same).

My question is, aren't both of them the similar function? (i.e., generate a whole bunch of random numbers).  If so, why is one giving me issues and the other is OK?

I post this is Quant since this is related to the implementation of quant models, hope that is OK.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: From the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rand.html): Calling `rand` with an integer input `n` will generate an `n-by-n` matrix. The integer does not seed the random number generator!

Comment: Ah...so I just so happened to use an integral value as a seed when using rand, but I guess it is completely wrong! Sorry, MATLAB noob here :)

Comment: When I try to use 'rng' in my script, I get error - "??? Undefined function or method 'rng' for input arguments of type 'char'." I have MATLAB R2010a installed in my system. What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `rng` does not do the same as `rand`. `rng` sets the seed for the random number generator and `rand` generates random numbers. Also it can be seen in documentation that the `rng` function only accepts positive integers. Usually random number generator algorithms start with integers for the seed. For various examples: C random function takes the system clock as seed as it does Minecraft's world generator.

Doc:

[`rnd`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/rng.html)

[`rand`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/rand.html)

Comment: Thanks, I think I was confused with the docs, thanks for pointing things out.